# PHP: change [img]src[/img] to <img src="src" alt="src" > with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to change `[img]src[/img]` to `<img src="src" alt="src" >` with regular expression.

I found some examples which convert `<img src="">` to `[img][/img]` but not my case.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799454/is-there-a-solid-bb-code-parser-for-php-that-doesnt-have-any-dependancies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive this article will help you with your problem...

http://thesinkfiles.hubpages.com/hub/Regex-for-BBCode-in-PHP

```
function parseCode($txt)
{
   // these functions will clean the code first
   $ret = strip_tags($txt);

   // code replacements
   $ret = preg_replace('#\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]#iUs', '<b>$1</b>', $ret);
   $ret = preg_replace('#\[link\=(.+)\](.+)\[\/link\]#iUs', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $ret);
   $ret = preg_replace('#\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]#iUs', '<img src="$1" alt="Image" />', $ret); 
   $ret = preg_replace('#\[quote\=(.+)\](.+)\[\/quote]#iUs', '<div class="quote">$2</div><div class="quote-by">By: $1</div>', $ret);


   // return parsed string
   return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ret = preg_replace('#\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]#iUs', '<img src="$1" alt="img">', $ret);
```

But in general you want something like a dedicated phpBB script, or phpBB class.
Even PHP itself got BBCode text processor: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can test it

```
 $str= preg_replace('~\[img\](.*)\[\/img\]~si', '<img src="$1" alt="$1">', $str);
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that you need to sanitize `$str` before this command to avoid a severe security flaw. ([`htmlentities($str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php))

Comment: @Yogu ok. but i only want to answer the question  no more