# adjust regex to look for an / on the end of an url

Tags: php, regex, url

I currently have this code:

```
// turn any url into url bbcode that doesn't have it already - so we can auto link urls- thanks stackoverflow
$URLRegex = '/(?:(?<!(\[\/url\]|\[\/url=))(\s|^))'; // No [url]-tag in front and is start of string, or has whitespace in front
$URLRegex.= '(';                                    // Start capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(https?|ftps?|ircs?):\/\/';            // Protocol
$URLRegex.= '\S+';                                  // Any non-space character
$URLRegex.= ')';                                    // Stop capturing URL
$URLRegex.= '(?:(?<![[:punct:]])(\s|\.?$))/i';      // Doesn't end with punctuation and is end of string, or has whitespace after

$body = preg_replace($URLRegex,"$2[url=$3]$3[/url]$5", $body);
```

Which looks for any urls, and turns them into bbcode (to auto link urls basically), problem is if one has a / on the end of it, it doesn't get parsed.

Can someone show me how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a [bbcode parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) instead? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799454/is-there-a-solid-bb-code-parser-for-php-with-no-dependencies

Comment: Try to edit this `$URLRegex.= '(?:(?<![[:punct:]])(\s|\.?$))/i';` to `$URLRegex.= '(?:(?<![[:punct:]])(\/|\s|\.?$))/i';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[[:punct:]]` in the negative look-behind will match `/` thereby preventing its inclusion in the match.

You could replace the `[[:punct:]]` with a character class containing all the specific characters you want to prevent from being the last character, e.g. `[.,;!?:\"\'()-]`.

Comment: I was just coming back to say it wasn't getting the ending slash! Thanks :D

Comment: @LiamDawe. I don't understand what you mean - please explain.

Comment: I meant i was coming back here as i realised it was happening but you already gave the answer here :)