# Using str_replace for forum post customisation

Tags: php, function, php-5.5

Right, basically I'm trying to create a function that will I can use to change user inputted tags like [b][/b] to strong -- /strong etc.

```
function wrap(){
    $content = 'Text [b]here[/b]... ';

    $replace = str_replace("[b]", "<strong>", $content);
    $replace = str_replace("[/b]", "</strong>", $content);
    echo $replace;  
}
```

When the user submits a new post, customising it using bold tags, em.. it will get displayed on the view post page...

```
<?php echo wrap("$post->postContent"); ?>
```

My question is how do I get this to work... I want to be able to create several replacements and just wrap each php echo with the function.

I've been playing with tons of alternative methods of code but none have proven to be completely successful.

---

**Irrelevant but possibly useful information.**

- OS: OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 (MacBook Pro)
- PHP Version 5.5.10 (MAMP PRO 3)
- Sublime Text 3 (Editor)

Comment: typo on the second replace? should probably be `[/b]`, since you're already destroying all of the `[b]` in the first replace.

Comment: plus have you considered http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php ?

Comment: Great spot, I missed that out when jotting it all down. Not sure the function works entirely tho.. something is missing!

Comment: http://elouai.com/bb2html.php.txt

Comment: What you typed should work fine. str_replace accepts arrays fyi

Answer (score 2):

This use case (i.e. parsing a complex markup language) is not one to which `str_replace` is amenable.

Moreover, without escaping of HTML entities, you leave yourself vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), among other things..

You should use a [BBCode parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799454/is-there-a-solid-bb-code-parser-for-php-with-no-dependencies).

Comment: Sounds brilliant, I'm just going to look into how to actual use a parser and try and get it working! But from what I've seen you've answered my overall question. Thanks pal!